# Sending multiple Python-clp data via Modbus TCP-IP

Tags: python-2.7, computer-vision, cpu-registers, clp

I am developing a project using Python language to develop computer vision code and need to send data to a PLC via Modbus TCP / IP communication. I have an established communication and I can only send information about a binary record, but I would like to send other resources from the identified object via Modbus as well, but I do not know how to use records in my favor.
Thanks, can anyone help me?

Comment: start by writing a wrapper in python for Modbus communication. Basically, have a function that pickles input data into text, sends it over via your communication channel and parses/pickles it on the other end. Then continue with the rest of the project.

Comment: Thanks ivan_a, I think this will help me a lot.